# How to know if FCM's `onLaunch` callback is gonna be called or not

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

So my project has the different navigation logic based on how user launch my app: by tap the icon laucher or via FCM's notification's tap. The case is I don't know if the FCM's `onLaunch` callback is gonna be called or not to decide which logic to use. Is there any good approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check how your activitiy is started like this (You can use invoke method of flutter to get this result in flutter)

```
if("android.intent.action.MAIN".equals(getIntent().getAction())){
            // By taping the icon launcher
        }else{
            //By other source 
        }
```